# Missing class details for [class]. Using existing class bytes for [class]

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipselink

EclipseLink 2.6.1 logs

> Missing class details for [class]

messages for some APIs like [`org.joda`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), session beans (EJBs) being deployed with the application, JPA static metamodel classes etc.

A few of them are as under:

```
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/LocalDate].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/LocalDate].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/ReadablePartial].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/ReadablePartial].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/base/BaseLocal].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/base/BaseLocal].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/base/AbstractPartial].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/base/AbstractPartial].
Finest:   Begin weaver class transformer processing class [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   Initializing compute class writer for [entity/UserTable]. Class loaders: context [16294f5] argument [12a6497].
Finest:   Visiting the end of the class [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   Adding _persistence_get() method into [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   Adding _persistence_set() method into [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   Weaved persistence (PersistenceEntity) [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   Weaved change tracking (ChangeTracker) [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   Weaved lazy (ValueHolder indirection) [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   Weaved fetch groups (FetchGroupTracker) [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   Weaved REST [entity/UserTable].
Finest:   End weaver class transformer processing class [entity/UserTable].
Info:   entity.UserTable actually got transformed
Info:   Portable JNDI names for EJB UserRegistrationBean: [java:global/Project/Project-ejb/UserRegistrationBean!client.services.UserRegistrationService, java:global/Project/Project-ejb/UserRegistrationBean]
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/ReadableInstant].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/ReadableInstant].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/Chronology].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/Chronology].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/chrono/ISOChronology].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/chrono/ISOChronology].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/chrono/AssembledChronology].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/chrono/AssembledChronology].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/chrono/BaseChronology].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/chrono/BaseChronology].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/DurationFieldType].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/DurationFieldType].
Finest:   Missing class details for [org/joda/time/DurationFieldType$StandardDurationFieldType].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [org/joda/time/DurationFieldType$StandardDurationFieldType].
Finest:   Missing class details for [admin/beans/OrderDetailsBean].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [admin/beans/OrderDetailsBean].
Finest:   Missing class details for [admin/services/OrderDetailsService].
Finest:   Using existing class bytes for [admin/services/OrderDetailsService].
Finest:   Begin weaver class transformer processing class [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   Initializing compute class writer for [entity/OrderTable]. Class loaders: context [16294f5] argument [12a6497].
Finest:   Visiting the end of the class [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   Adding _persistence_get() method into [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   Adding _persistence_set() method into [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   Weaved persistence (PersistenceEntity) [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   Weaved change tracking (ChangeTracker) [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   Weaved lazy (ValueHolder indirection) [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   Weaved fetch groups (FetchGroupTracker) [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   Weaved REST [entity/OrderTable].
Finest:   End weaver class transformer processing class [entity/OrderTable].
Info:   entity.OrderTable actually got transformed
Finest:   Begin weaver class transformer processing class [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   Initializing compute class writer for [entity/OrderItem]. Class loaders: context [16294f5] argument [12a6497].
Finest:   Visiting the end of the class [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   Adding _persistence_get() method into [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   Adding _persistence_set() method into [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   Weaved persistence (PersistenceEntity) [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   Weaved change tracking (ChangeTracker) [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   Weaved lazy (ValueHolder indirection) [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   Weaved fetch groups (FetchGroupTracker) [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   Weaved REST [entity/OrderItem].
Finest:   End weaver class transformer processing class [entity/OrderItem].
```

persistence.xml :

```xml
<properties>
    <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.cache" value="FINEST"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
</properties>
```

The application is deployed under GlassFish Server 4.1 / Java EE 7. This had not been happening util EclipseLink 2.6.0.

What does this message mean?

> Missing class details for [class]

---

**Update :**

The same logs continue in EclipseLink 2.6.2 released on December 22, 2015

Answer (score 0):

This is just a message that these classes could not be woven, because they're not Entity classes. This is totally fine, as all your Entity classes are woven as the other log messages show.

You can ignore this message.